# How to see git log on the given moved file with diffs

Tags: git, logging

Yes, I can do that with help of next command:

```
$ git log -p -M
commit 9841f31f283c74ec9e2a33869590d976091cf191
Author: user
Date:   Sat Apr 4 09:58:12 2015 +0300

    Move file

diff --git a/test.pl b/test/test.pl
similarity index 85%
rename from test.pl
rename to test/test.pl
index dd0479d..0d880c8 100644
--- a/test.pl
+++ b/test/test.pl
@@ -2,4 +2,5 @@

 use Modern::Perl;

+#comment
 say "Hello, world";
```

But in my case I have handred files, so I want to restrict log messages to certain one

```
$ git log -p -M test.pl 
commit 9841f31f283c74ec9e2a33869590d976091cf191
Author: user
Date:   Sat Apr 4 09:58:12 2015 +0300

    Move file

diff --git a/test/test.pl b/test/test.pl
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..0d880c8
--- /dev/null
+++ b/test/test.pl
@@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
+#/usr/bin/perl
+
+use Modern::Perl;
+
+#comment
+say "Hello, world";
```

As you can see `diff --git a/test/test.pl b/test/test.pl` git do not recognize rename in this case.

Is that the git BUG or must I use different options?

**ANSWER** just want to show output in my case:

```
$ git log -p --follow test.pl
commit 9841f31f283c74ec9e2a33869590d976091cf191
Author: user
Date:   Sat Apr 4 09:58:12 2015 +0300

    Move file

diff --git a/test.pl b/test/test.pl
similarity index 85%
rename from test.pl
rename to test/test.pl
index dd0479d..0d880c8 100644
--- a/test.pl
+++ b/test/test.pl
@@ -2,4 +2,5 @@

 use Modern::Perl;

+#comment
 say "Hello, world";
```

If you notice, with this flag `--follow` diff do right thing:

`diff --git a/test.pl b/test/test.pl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want here is the `--follow` option

> ```
>   --follow
>       Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames (works only 
>       for a single file).
> ```

Try `git log -p --follow test.pl`.

An example in a test repository looks like:

```
commit 16da3d589da102e11c822b0bec931eed41c35e25
Author: John Szakmeister <john@szakmeister.net>
Date:   Sat Apr 4 04:19:51 2015 -0400

    rename and add *

diff --git a/foo.txt b/bar.txt
similarity index 92%
rename from foo.txt
rename to bar.txt
index 0ff3bbb..e431201 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/bar.txt
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
 10
 11
 12
-13
+13*
 14
 15
 16

commit 3eaef5c6993c6f7df4df457359cb21da8ab75539
Author: John Szakmeister <john@szakmeister.net>
Date:   Sat Apr 4 04:19:16 2015 -0400

    add foo

diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..0ff3bbb
--- /dev/null
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,20 @@
+1
+2
+3
+4
+5
+6
+7
+8
+9
+10
+11
+12
+13
+14
+15
+16
+17
+18
+19
+20
```

Without `--follow`, you get:

```
commit 16da3d589da102e11c822b0bec931eed41c35e25
Author: John Szakmeister <john@szakmeister.net>
Date:   Sat Apr 4 04:19:51 2015 -0400

    rename and add *

diff --git a/bar.txt b/bar.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e431201
--- /dev/null
+++ b/bar.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,20 @@
+1
+2
+3
+4
+5
+6
+7
+8
+9
+10
+11
+12
+13*
+14
+15
+16
+17
+18
+19
+20
```